# Is it possible to successfully integrate jotform with asp platform, without loosing the js validations?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jotform

I am using jotform, a pretty good form builder (WYSIYYG).
I have created a form, and downloaded the source code and put it in my asp.net page. The content and styles and visual aspects are fine, but I lost all the js validations ( the warnings doesn't show up if an input is required, etc).

Has anyone accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems integrating with the page the best solution is to use the IFrame code option. It prevents conflicts with the page.

Here is how you can get the iframe code.

1. Open your form on the [Form Builder](http://www.jotform.com):
2. Click "Setup & Embed" tab on toolbar
3. Click on "Embed Form"
4. Click on "iFrame".